# Find parallel line value

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've an homework problem that i'm unable to find the right answer.

The problem is:

The line $tx + sy = 2$ goes through point $(2,1)$ and is parallel to line $y = 8 -3x$, find the value of $t^2 + s^2$.

$ A. {32\over49}$ $B.{18\over49}$ $C.{36\over49}$ $D.{25\over49} $ $E.{40\over49} $

I was able to find a parallel line at $ y = -3x + 7 $ but i'm unable to find any of the possible answers to be right.

Comment: What does parallel means in terms of slope? This already gives you the answer to find one relation for $s$ and $t$ Plugging in (2,1) gives you another relation for $s$ and $t$. Two equations with 2 unknowns.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite $y = -3x + 7$ in the form $tx + sy = 2$: $$\begin{align*}y & = -3x + 7 \\ 3x + y & = 7 \\ \frac{6}{7} x + \frac{2}{7} y & = 2.\end{align*}$$ By comparison of the form of $\frac{6}{7} x + \frac{2}{7} y = 2$ to that of $tx + sy = 2$, we find $t = \frac{6}{7}$ and $s = \frac{2}{7}$. Therefore, $$t^2 + s^2 = {\left(\frac{6}{7}\right)}^2 + {\left(\frac{2}{7}\right)}^2 = \frac{40}{49}.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$tx + sy = 2$ parallel to $y=-3x+8$ implies $$-3=-\dfrac{t}{s}.$$

$tx + sy = 2$ goes through $(2,1)$ means $$2t+s=2.$$

You have two unknowns and two equations. Solve the system and you'll have the answer.

Comment: How does the parallel equations implies that `-3 = -t/s` ?

Comment: Note that $tx+sy=2\implies sy=-tx+2\implies y=-\dfrac{t}{s}x+\dfrac{2}{s}.$ That is, its slope is $-t/s.$ Since it is parallel to $y=-3x+7$, which has slope $-3,$ we get the desired equality.